# what is top level module in Python?

Tags: python

I've met words such as  top-level modules and top-level packages in Python documentation several times. [This is the documentation about such concepts.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import)
What does these words mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modules can be nested inside each other. For example `os.path` is a `path` module nested inside `os` module. Top level module is the topmost one. I this case, it's an `os` module.

Comment: So both modules and packages have such construct hierarchy, am i right?

Comment: Package is module which can contain more modules inside it: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package

Comment: Thank you so much.Now i have a clearer understanding of modules.